# Manage custom menu for an Editor?

Tags: menus, permissions

I've a problem with permission. Is there a specific permission to let an user with Editor Role, manage the custom menu of a theme, and *only this options?*

The item that is under Appereance -> Menu, to be clear.

I'm using the capability plugin. 
Must I write a custom hook to enable only the use of custom menu editor ?

TIA

Edit:
I've code a simple solution. See below my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the editor role the 'edit_theme_options' permission, but that will also unlock other theme options like widgets to those users.

Comment: Yes, true. This was what I did. This is not exactly what I need. Thanks. I'll try to write a custom hook...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found a way, using the admin_menu action. I post here, in case someone needs it.

This code remove for a specific user all the submenus items except the one for the custom menus in the *Appereance* menu.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'enable_only_custom_menu');

function enable_only_custom_menu() {
    global $menu,$submenu;
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if ($current_user->user_login == 'username') {
        foreach($submenu['themes.php'] as $key=>$smenu) {
            if ($smenu[2] != 'nav-menus.php') {
                unset($submenu['themes.php'][$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You must iterate the submenu for the key 'themes.php' and deleting all the items that are not interisting for you.

Comment: Unsetting the menu item may literally stop the user accessing a given page, but that doesn't necessarily mean they can't perform a given action. I'm thinking out loud here, but i'd suggesting looking at `$wp_post_types` and tweaking the nav menu post-type. When i say tweak i mean hook in and swap out the required capabilities for that type with custom ones(then you can assign those caps as you choose).

Comment: ..following on... Nav menus are post types, so like any other post type they have a set of capabilities required to manage them, hooking in at an appropriate point might provide a means for tweaking the capabilities required to manage that post type(custom caps, or whatever).